# mysqli_query not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am writing to display slide items from my database but despite the connection to the database It always displays Error message. In my case it displays below error.

> **Record Fetching Error**

Please advise me the error here.

```
function slide() {
    $link = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);
    if (!$link) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sn_slides WHERE publish=1 order by ordering asc,slideId desc limit 5";
    $quer = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if (!is_resource($quer)) {
        die("Record Fetching Error ");
    }
    $arReturn = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($quer)) {
        $arReturn[] = $row;
    }
    return $arReturn;
}
```

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`  dump that in reload and try and see what it says

Comment: use `mysqli_error($link)` on the `if (!is_resource($quer))` block to see what was wrong.

Comment: Try your query direct in phpMyAdmin or by command line.